# Swift IOS capture html form input in realtime jquery

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm trying to capture a text input in a html form in real time in my webview.  I'm currently using jquery to capture the text input change and then forward the value through a url that I intercept.  I am able to capture each change in the text input but the issue I'm having is my text input loses focus on every new character entered, I have to reclick the text input to continue entering each time (window.location.href causes it to lose focus every time its triggered).  Im using the following code:

```
var form = "
<form class="search_extended">
<input style="" type="text" name="name" id="search_field">
<input type='hidden' name='page' value='name_search'>
</form>"

var script = "
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("form input, form textarea").on("input propertychange change", function() {
var search_serialized = $(".search_extended").serialize();
window.location.href = "?" + search_serialized; 
});});</script>"

script = script + "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"

self.webView_Search_Extended.loadHTMLString(form + script, baseURL: nil)
```

Capture forwarding URL

```
   func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    print(request.url?.absoluteString)
    var url = request.url?.absoluteString
return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that by using

`window.location.href = "?" + search_serialized;`

to call the url that your delegate catches, caused the text field to blur.

You will probably want to use a special link in your webpage that can be caught (so it doesn't catch all loads) and return false from the delegate for this:

```
var form = "
<form class="search_extended">
<input style="" type="text" name="name" id="search_field">
<input type='hidden' name='page' value='name_search'>
</form>"

var script = "
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("form input, form textarea").on("input propertychange change", function() {
var search_serialized = $(".search_extended").serialize();
window.location.href = "my-form-scheme://" + search_serialized;
});});</script>"

script = script + "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"

self.webView_Search_Extended.loadHTMLString(form + script, baseURL: nil)
```

And then for the delegate:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if request.url?.scheme == "my-form-scheme" {
        print(request.url?.absoluteString)
        var url = request.url?.absoluteString
        return false // this is the important bit
    }
    return true
}
```

So you make sure that you only catch the special url posted by your form event, and return false, which will hopefully prevent the blur.

Comment: You are a life savor!  Do you know the reason behind using a custom scheme why it doesn't cause the blur?  I'm kinda stumped on why it works this way.

Comment: @user2423476 It's not actually the custom scheme here that does this, the custom scheme just makes it easy to catch the specific call (I wasn't sure if perhaps you would have other calls from the webview too, plus it makes the answer more applicable to any other users who may come across it). The bit making the different is `return false`, inside that conditional. When you return true you are telling the webview that it is ok to load the request, which in this case is reloading the page, which in turn blurs all inputs on the page. Returning false lets you catch the data, but not do a reload.